# Pandas - Split string column into multiple rows on punctuation

Tags: pandas

So I have this code that looks at each string in each row and creates a substring from the beginning to the index of the punctuation character unless it's the last character. So I can have a row like this:

```
     label       msg
0    0           hello there, how are you doing?
1    1           Hi! I got a new product for you. Would you like to know more?
2    0           It's Taco Tuesday man
```

This should become

```
     label       msg
0    0           hello there,
1    1           Hi! 
2    1           Hi! I got a new product for you.
```

I have code below for doing it but it's painfully slow. I'd love to know a more efficient method for doing this.

```
call_table_df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Data/call_table_user_only.csv')
negative_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=call_table_df.columns)

for df_idx, row in call_table_df.iterrows():
  punc_idxs = [i for i, c in enumerate(row["message"]) if c in [",", ".", "?"]]
  
  if len(punc_idxs) > 1:
    original_msg = row["message"]
    for i in punc_idxs:
      if i < len(original_msg) - 1:
        # print(original_msg[:i + 1])
        row["message"] = original_msg[:i + 1]
        row["length"] = i + 1
        negative_df = negative_df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with a regex with a lookbehind, then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and remove the last sentence with [`groupby.head(-1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.head.html):

```
out = (df.assign(msg=df['msg'].str.split(r'(?<=[^\w\s])\s+'))
         .explode('msg')
         .groupby(level=0).head(-1)
      )
```

*NB. if you want to split after specific characters (e.g. `,`, `!`, `.`), use `(?<=[,!.])\s+`.*

Output:

```
   label                           msg
0      0                  hello there,
1      1                           Hi!
1      1  I got a new product for you.
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eduQi9/1)

If you want a cumulatively increasing string, add a step with a custom function:

```
def f(s):
    out = s[:1]
    for x in s[1:]:
        out.append(out[-1]+' '+x)
    return out
        
out = (df.assign(msg=df['msg'].str.split(r'(?<=[^\w\s])\s+').apply(f))
         .explode('msg')
         .groupby(level=0).head(-1)
      )
```

Output:

```
   label                               msg
0      0                      hello there,
1      1                               Hi!
1      1  Hi! I got a new product for you.
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'label': [0, 1, 0],
                     'msg': ['hello there, how are you doing?',
                             'Hi! I got a new product for you. Would you like to know more?',
                             "It's Taco Tuesday man"]})
```

Comment: sorry I made a modification to the question so the last row or your example should be "Hi! I got a new product for you." so it should include the strings that come before it as well.

Comment: @Gooby so you want to increment the string? Can you provide a slightly more complex example to illustrate what happens with 2 or 3 chunks?

Comment: yea so if you get something like "Hi! How are you? I'm good. What's new?" It should create new rows "Hi!", "Hi! How are you?" and "Hi! How are you? I'm good." The horribly inefficient code written above is exactly what should happen. I just want to do it more panda-like cause it's pretty bad currently.

Comment: @Gooby see update, but keep in mind that generating an increasing chunk string will always be somehow costly.

Comment: I'm sure it's faster than what I wrote it's actually horrible to look at.

Comment: Let me know the timings ;)

Comment: well your code finished on 180k rows in seconds what I had above didn't finish in 20 minutes so way faster.